# Windows guest OS systems should work only when joined to domain

Tags: windows, active-directory

This is my first question and I request your patience here,
In our production environment, we have predominantly windows based servers and workstations and hosted on vmware. 
The development team has access to vcenter and they create vms based on the approved templates.
However, we recently realized that many of these servers are not joined to domain and they are used in workgroup ( as they have local admin rights)
Is there a way to enforce these systems to join to the domain, or restrict the system functionality until it is joined to our domain.
Windows OS Server family ( 2008 R2 and above till 2016)
Windows Destkop ( 7 and 10)
Active directory is 2012r2 domain specific environment.

Thanks in advance for your co-operation.

Thanks,
Mohan

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to enforce these systems to join to the domain, or
>   restrict the system functionality until it is joined to our domain.

No, there isn't. This is a process problem and needs a process solution. There is no technical solution for this.

Edit, I forgot about doing an unattended domain join until Michael Hampton reminded me in his comment. You could force these VM's to join the domain as part of the deployment process. Have a read at the link below:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/update-windows-settings-and-scripts-create-your-own-answer-file-sxs

Comment: Can't the VM join the domain at first boot, e.g. from unattend.xml?

Comment: That's true.. they could join the domain unattended.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, this is interesting,could you please share some information,or any article related to it.

Comment: @joeqwerty,-Thank you very much, that gives me hope.

Comment: If you want to know how to join Windows machines to a domain via an unattended deployment, I suggest you do some very basic googling about the deployment product you're using (Vmware templates?) and domain joins.